# Insert Query for more than 100 records not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program which runs Foreach Loop to Check the member details and insert respective data into database.
I store all members data into array first then insert batch data into database.
Currently I have 300 members to loop into foreach. also I remove the empty data from the array. It woks fine on Localhost. But when I try it on server it gives "500 Internal Server Error".

What is going wrong? How to optimize the program?

thanks!

Comment: Check your error logs, what did they give back?

Comment: @hd I found the error_log, it shows - "[warn] mod_fcgid: process 11922 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL"

Comment: @tushAR, how you are passing data to Database from front-end?

Comment: @AjithaMs Which permissions I need to check?

Comment: @tushAR SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT permissions on the user you're using to connect to the database. Also, ensure that user is added to the database which those permissions! Also, make sure your user has the Host `127.0.0.1`/`localhost`.

Comment: may be i think it is due to default execution time try by increasing the default execution time by ini_set(50) before your function

Comment: @rohitr it is set to set_time_limit(0); execute for unknown time

Comment: try using ini_set('max_execution_time', seconds);

Comment: @rohitr its working for 2 time only but the same problem again. :(

Comment: try increasing seconds more as i think sometimes it taking more time .

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you insert a single record on your server? Assuming you are able to connect to the database and your table structure is the same as offline

Comment: AT first I am inserting records by records but I get the same problem. I thought it was performance issue and I change the code to insert records in batch.

Comment: If I tried with minimum records, they are inserted easily.

Comment: Its just simple DB program runs in foreach loop and collect records in batch. and inserts at last.